# How to Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+2}{x^4+4} \ dx$ given $\mathcal{F}_c(e^{-x}\cos(x))=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{k^2+2}{k^4+4}$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, fourier-analysis

I have previously shown that ($\mathcal{F}_c(f(x))$ denotes the Fourier cosine transform of $f(x)$) $$\mathcal{F}_c(e^{-x}\cos(x))=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{k^2+2}{k^4+4} \tag{1}.$$ Using this information, I am trying to solve the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+2}{x^4+4} \ dx.$$
I thought the problem could be solved by taking the inverse Fourier cosine transform of $(1)$:
$$e^{-x}\cos(x)=\mathcal{F}_c^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{k^2+2}{k^4+4}\right).$$ But clearly this leads to 
$$e^{-x}\cos(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{k^2+2}{k^4+4}\cos(kx) \ dk.$$
I do not require a full solution at this stage, just a **hint** on how to proceed. I wish to solve this homework problem as much as I can.

Comment: Can you put $x=0$ in your last equation?

Comment: I don't even think you need anything as advanced as Fourier transforms. Using partial fraction decomposition works for me to get the antiderivative.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated true, but the question specifically asks to use the prior result.

Comment: @Chip I don't see why not! Can you think of a reason why this substitution isn't valid? Nice thinking.